# How to eliminate the Rate and Feedback bar at the top of help pages in Visual Studio 2005 and 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Using MS Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 help viewer (MS Document Explorer), on virtually every help page I get a "**Send/Add Content.../Rate and Feedback**" bar at the top of the page. The problem is that this bar is overlayed on the page itself by the viewer, and obscures the top part of it.

Here's a sample:

[image]

Is there a way to eliminate this bar?

Answer (score 1):

I have VS2008, so hopefully it is the same for VS2005. I would do this:

Go to Tools>Options>Environment>Help Make sure that "Show Help using" is set to "External Help Viewer" in the drop-down box.

If that does not solve your problem, you can go to Tools>Options>Environment>Help>Online and set "When loading Help content" to "Try local only, not online".

You cannot remove that bar as an option since it is part of the web page that you are downloading as part of the online help pages.

Comment: Thanks, KCotreau. The bar appears in both external and internal viewers. I don't have MSDN installed locally do for me the online version is the only way to go. viewing at the source of the page, it seems like the bar is embedded in the HTML source (this is an utterly stupid idea, if you ask me). However, I suspect that it is added by the server upon request of the page. I wonder how to eliminate this...

Comment: @ysap Funny, it did not appear there for me in VS2008 (again, I did not have VS2005 any more to look at) when I went to only local. I actually tested that on my server before I answered.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense that when you are offline, there will be no feedback option... Thanks!